# Is it possible to obtain all Google scholar profiles without entering anything in the search box?

Tags: web-scraping, google-scholar

Is there any way to not write anything in the search box to get all the google scholar profiles?
So that I can scrape all the information about them (name, job, interests)

[image: Google Scholar Profiles Search]

What's only available to search with anything but I don't want that.
[image]

Comment: Either ask Google whether they provide an API for this, or use another service. Scraping their website might be against their TOS, and violating it might lead to your scraper being blocked